# How to split /t without create a new line using Python

Tags: python

I have lists of text in one folder :

```
My O
name O
is O
Alex B
. O

I O
am O
from O
London B
. O
```

This is my codes:

```
import re

def read_file(filename):

file = open(filename).read().strip().split("\n\n")
lines = []
for line in file:

 lines.append(re.split(r'\t|\n', line))

return lines

train_sents = read_file(("train.txt"))

train_sents [0]
```

The output is:

```
 [ 'My',
 'O',
 'name',
 'O',
 "is',
 'O',
 'Alex',
 'B',
 '.',
 'O']
```

My question is..is it possible to split \t without splitting it to the new line? For the example the output will be like:

```
[('My', 'O'),
 ('name', 'O'),
 ("is', 'O'),
 ('Alex', 'B'),
 ('.', 'O')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just split each line:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    print([tuple(line.split()) for line in f])
[('My', 'O'), ('name', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('Alex', 'B'), ('.', 'O')]
```

To separate the lines by empty lines append to the last sublist or else add a new list if we meet an empty line:

```
with open(infile) as f:
    l = [[]]
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            l[-1].append(tuple(line.split()))
        else:
            l.append([])
print(l[0])
print(l[1])

[('My', 'O'), ('name', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('Alex', 'B'), ('.', 'O')]
[('I', 'O'), ('am', 'O'), ('from', 'O'), ('London', 'B'), ('.', 'O')]
```

You could also use i[tertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) grouping using empty lines as the delimiter:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open(infile) as f:
     print([list(map(str.split, v))
       for k, v in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x.strip() != "") if k])


[[['My', 'O'], ['name', 'O'], ['is', 'O'], ['Alex', 'B'], ['.', 'O']], [['I', 'O'], ['am', 'O'], ['from', 'O'], ['London', 'B'], ['.', 'O']]]
```

You can map to tuple if necessary.

Comment: note that , he wants the above output while printing `train_sents[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
def read_file(filename):
    fil = open(filename).read().strip().split("\n\n")
    lines = []
    for line in fil:
        s = []
        m = line.split('\n')
        for i in m:
            s.append(tuple(re.split(r'\t', i)))
        lines.append(s)    
    return lines

train_sents = read_file("file")

print train_sents[0]
```

**Output:**

```
[('My', 'O'), ('name', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('Alex', 'B'), ('.', 'O')]
```

Comment: I have tried but my out :

         [('My', 'O'), ('name', 'O'), ("'is", 'O'), ('Alex', 'B'),]
 
 but  \n not split to the new line. Or is it same actually?

Comment: Are you trying to get output like in the format like you mentioned? Why what's the actual use of that? Note that both are same.